# Repair UEFI boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

I have laptop with two HDD. Each HDD has its own Windows 10 installation. Bios mode is UEFI. I have change boot sequence in bios and start system from second disc. System has done some windows update, but next time I was trying boot my first hdd it failed and got into repair mode. How to get back my main system that in picture below is shown as volume D. Picture is taken while booted from second HDD.

[image]

UPD

I have removed my second drive and have booted in recovery mode. I got to command prompt and this is how my partitions look like:

[image]

UPD 2

I used `DISKPART` and assigned drive letter to system partition:

```
assign letter=s
```

then

```
bcdboot c:\Windows /s S: /f EFI
```

And not got blue screen with error:

```
Your device needs to be repaired:

\Windows\system32\driver\pdc.sys
error code 0x000000d
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is to use diskpart to delete the corrupt EFI partition, create a new one and add the boot files for the new Partition with bcdboot

I suggest you unplug your 2nd drive before so you don't accidentally mess with the wrong partitions.

1. Create USB Boot Stick (Windows Media creation tool) and boot from it
2. press Shift + F10 (you might need to go through a few windows first)
3. type **diskpart** -> **list disk** -> **sel disk x** (x being the number of your HDD in the list) -> **list part** .> **sel part x** (x being the number of your efi part) -> **del part x** -> **create partition efi** -> **format quick fs=fat32**
4. type *exit*
5. in the command prompt, type **bcdboot C:\Windows**. If it wants you to specify the target part, try assigning a letter to the EFI in diskpart and use the /s switch (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di?view=windows-11)

Exit, shutdown, disconnect USB, boot up, see if it works.

Comment: But if I perform `del part x ` I will loose all my data

Comment: Probably the del and (re)create is unnecessary. Just (re)format it should do.

Comment: I have removed my second drive and have booted in recovery mode. More details in UPD in question body

Comment: The partition with type `System` is the one you should rebuild.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you run `bcdboot` with `/f UEFI` specified btw.

Comment: I did `c:\Windows /s S: /f EFI` but after reboot got error. More details in UPD 2 in question body

Comment: Have you formatted the partition before you run `bcdboot`? In any case, I never really felt like it is a problem caused by the ESP or the update. Probably your hard drive just happened to fail to a certain extent. (Maybe you should consider start backing up user data on the drive in concern.)

Comment: The flag should be **/f UEFI** , not EFI