# Access denied to NTFS drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have two system hdd's connected to my laptop. After some [manipulation with partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/1719629/repair-uefi-boot/1719632#1719632) I can't acess second drive anymore:

Got error:

```
Location is not available
D:\ is not accessible.
Access is denied.
```

[image]

How to fix that?

Comment: Am I right in assuming that this partition contains another Win10 OS? Are your credentials for both OS'es the same, including administrator accounts? Is the other disk encrypted perhaps (for example with Bitlocker)?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried viewing Ownership properties?

Right-click on the inaccessible hard drive, select Properties.
Go to the Security tab, hit Advanced, then click the Edit button.
On the Owner tab, modify the ownership of the specified account.